# UIKit TabBar with SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am updating my existing UIKit to use SwiftUI in some parts where I feel comfortable about being able to replace all of it with SwiftUI. It is a tab application, so there are 3 tabs and one of it are Settings, which I am replacing with SwiftUI.
My tab bar is configured to only show images and no titles (the issue I need help with would also occur with labels shown).
Now in UIKit I do this:

`private let settingsViewController: UIViewController = UIHostingController<SettingsView>(SettingsView())`

and later on before showing it:

`settingsViewController.navigationItem.title = "Settings"`.

However from then on SwiftUI takes on with its view modifier: `.navigationBarTitle("Text")`, which I use for nested view controllers (pushed via `NavigationLink`), as UIKit cannot access those views to set a title.
The issue is however, that whenever `.navigationBarTitle` is used (same with setting the view's `title` property in UIKit, it sets the current tab bar items title. For UIKit there is always a way to set the `navigationItem.title` instead of `title`.

Is there any way to set the navigation bar title but not the tab bar title itself in SwiftUI?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and can reproduce this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to be a bug in iOS. Please file a bug report to Apple.

I just discovered [a workaround for this issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/gh6fm3/tab_bar_issues_in_mixed_swiftuiuikit_apps_on_ios/):

Create a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` and use it as the navigation controller containing your `settingsViewController`.

```swift
class WorkaroundUINavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var title: String? {
       get { tabBarItem.title }
       set { navigationItem.title = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It's annoying the the "fix" is clean at least. FYI this still happens on iOS 14 but seems to be resolved on iOS 15